# How do the residents of Attilan speak English?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, inhumans-2017

The residents of Attilan, the Inhuman city on the Moon, speak perfect English. It’s not merely a translation convention, because Triton, Gorgon, and Medusa were able to communicate readily with ordinary residents of Oahu.

Why is this? Was the city founded relatively recently by English-speaking individuals? Do they have some sort of universal translator? Or is it something else altogether?

Comment: Inhumans originated on Earth and eventually migrated to the moon. As evident by the recent rise of Inhumans on Earth (re Agents of SHIELD) who are said to be descendants of original Inhumans who were left behind. And English has been around a long time. And Attilan is seen monitoring activites on Earth. They could easily pick up Earth's TV and radio transmissions and hear modern dialects

Comment: @Remy - English has been around a long time, yes...but people from 1600 would already be almost incomprehensible to most modern-day people. And that's if you didn't let their language diverge a bit for 400 years. Practically speaking, I couldn't see an isolated population sounding anything like modern English unless they were 1800s or later. The Royals I suppose could maintain their English skills if they needed to, but the general population doesn't seem to be able to spy on Earth whenever.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate to all the 'why everyone speak english' posts ? I guess we can try to find in-universe reason, but let's be serious, the real reason is out of universe and is 'because it's way more convenient'. Basically they have their own language on Attilan, and the royals/expeditionary also speak/understand english.

Comment: What DNA said. It's almost always the same answer for all works. Everyone speaks English because, out-of-universe, every other option is inconvenient and distracts from the story. Unless we have a story that is actually about language barriers (like Arrival or Star Trek's Darmok), all of these explanations (Universal Translator, Babelfish, telepathic TARDIS translator) are only devices to explain this conceit so they can get on with the story.

Comment: @JDoe - Be that as it may, the explanation of the conceit *is* important. Not necessarily its specific nature (though that can be interesting, too), but the fact that there is one. Anyway, it’s not usually the same answer at all. People in *Harry Potter* speak English because they live in Britain. People “speak English” in *The Lord of the Rings*  or *Star Wars* or *The Broken Earth* because there’s a translation convention for the audience. People in *The Beyonders* “speak English” because of an ambient magical effect.

Comment: @Adamant Your comment doesn't explain why such explanations are important as you say.

Comment: @JDoe - Because people want to know them. ;) Is there another reason with fiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They monitor Earth, and as they knew one day they would need to go there, it could easily be in their education system for when they do go (in order to communicate).  They likely keep up with the most popular language there.

Or they just have a translator somewhere. It's been confirmed the Guardians of the Galaxy don't actually speak English and will use translators for Infinity War. Perhaps the Inhumans have similar ones we simply don't see, just like the Avengers commlinks.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange! Please include references and quotes to improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

<s>In the episode 1.04, we get a very import information about the moon base creation.

I can't access the show right now to give the precise script, but basically Crystal (the blond princess) says they use Lockjaw (The big teleporting dog) abilities to go to the moon.

That means they went there during their life (or at least during the life of Lockjaw)</s>

In this case, it makes sense they speaks an existing human language.

You can still argue it would make more sense that they speak Chinese or Spanish, because it would be way easier to hide a city in the heart of China/Amazonia than in the US.
But it now revert to the classic "Everyone speak the native language of the watcher" question.

Edit after 1.07
First of all, forget about everything above, i misunderstood the line, they were talking about the trip from moon to earth (relating to the show), not the migration from earth to moon.
But, and more close to the question.

### They clearly don't *write* in English on Attilan.

[image: wrinting exemple 2]
[image: writing exemple 1]
Yes, the question was about speaking, but speaking and writing tends to be related.

The flag could still be a 'high speech' thing, used only in specific occasion. But the Karnak scene implies this alphabet (and the matching language) is his thought language.